# Path planning algorithm for connected multi-robot system

Tags: algorithm, robotics, motion-planning

Say I have three robots connected as a triangle, how do I manage to avoid obstacles in working space?

I'm thinking about using A*, but I got problem that it works for one robots but when comes to 3 robots it will cause collision.

I'm really new to robotics, could anyone at least have some idea that which algorithm will be a better fit?

I don't need the actual code, just a feasible idea is fine.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. How are the robots connected? If they are connected, why wouldn't you treat them as a unit when finding a path?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'connected as a triangle'? Are they attached to inflexible rods and must move simultanously, or are they 'connected' in terms of communication?